# JavaScript .play() and .pause() not working

Tags: javascript, html, audio, playback, pause

I'm new to JavaScript and am having trouble using the .play() and .pause() functions. I've looked this up online but can't find many answers and any that do appear don't seem to help.

HTML

```
<audio src="audiofile.mp3" id="audio" preload="auto" loop></audio>
<img id="bttn" onclick="playpause();" src="funbutton.gif">
```

JavaScript

```
var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
function playpause() {
    if (audio.paused);
        audio.play();
    else;
        audio.pause();
}
```

The reason I want to do this is so that I don't have to use the browsers default controls and I only want the play and pause functions since it's a looping background track that the user can choose to put on.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your JS logic syntax is incorrect. Here's how you'd write your if/else:

```js
var audio = document.getElementById("audio");

function playpause() {
  if (audio.paused) {
    audio.play();
  } else {
    audio.pause();
  }
}
```

```html
<audio src="audiofile.mp3" id="audio" preload="auto" loop></audio>
<img id="bttn" onclick="playpause();" src="funbutton.gif">
```

Comment: use  $("#audioContainer").get(0).pause();

Comment: @kinsleykajiva Why? My solution (which is over 1 year old) works, and your comment has jQuery code which this question does not mention.

Comment: i did try it for real , but it didn't work i tested this in Chrome ,but it was throwing an exception"Function not found" so i tested the above solution . But if it worked some one well OK thus great .

Answer (score 0):

Just delete ";" in If Else Statements or use :

```
if(...){
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The if else blocks are written incorrectly. If-else blocks should look like this:

```
if(condition){
//do something
} else {
// do something else
}
```

Alternatively, you could remove the html and play the mp3 audio file just using javascript:

```
 var audio = new Audio("filename");
 function playpause(){
    if(audio.paused){
     audio.play();
    } else {
     audio.pause();
    }
 }
```